# npx create-nuxt-app <project-name> not working

Tags: javascript, npm, nuxt.js, npx

I want to create Nuxt.Js app using npx. But i am getting following error. 
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a space in your Windows username. This is a problem with **NPX**.

This is the path that **NPM** sees (which is right)

- [image: Right path]

This is the path that **NPX** sees (which is wrong)

- [image]

You can fix it by changing your NPM-Cache to another directory (without a space in the path):

```
npm config set cache C:\your\new\path\npm-cache --global
```

Source:
https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146#issuecomment-384016791

Answer (score 3):

I changed npm-cache directory by writing following command

```
npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global
```

After that `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I had it working using this command.

`npm init nuxt-app <project-name>`

Comment: Indemna does this command replace `npx create-nuxt-app`?  is the `create-nuxt-app` obsolete?

Comment: hi @Chris22, no, this is not a replacement and it does not make `create-nuxt-app` obsolete. It's just an alternative command as stated in the documentation. https://zh.nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/installation/#using-create-nuxt-app

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved in a reddit

https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/ie8vab/createnuxtapp_not_working_anyone_else_had_this/

Install it with:

```
npm i -g create-nuxt-app
```

Usually npm/npx should propose you to install, but it might not work
This issue can appear if during first try the installation was aborted

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem and I have multiple spaces in the username.

If the above solutions does not work for you on Windows, there is another way.

1. Run VS code editor as an administrator.
2. Open the integrated terminal by clicking on **Terminal** > **New Terminal** or by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + '
3. Instead of using npx use the following

   > npm init nuxt-app project-name

Point number 3 will only work if you run the VS code editor as Administrator. 
I am sure it is the same with external terminals. Run CMD/Gitbash as Administrator

Hope this helps. :D

Comment: is there a difference using `npm` vs. `npx`?  I'm following a tutorial and the instructor uses `npx create` command instead of `npm init`.  Thanks

Comment: @Chris22 Yes, there's a difference. Using `npm`, the package is installed globally or locally, whereas, in the case of `npx`, the script is executed without installing the package at all.